# Bootstrap3 problems with grid layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am creating a grid based landing page with lots of nested columns. Was going well until I completed the load of nested columns and then the next row seems to overlap. In the code below the new container and row appear over the top of the last nested row. I'm sure its something really simple but I can't see where I've gone wrong and would appreciate the help.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 mainImage">
                Image

            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 panel2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 panel3"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 panel4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 panel3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 panel3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 panel2"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 panel3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 panel3"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 panel2"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 panel4">
    </div>

</div>-->
```

Comment: Do a demo on bootply.com, it;s much easier to debug.

Comment: You are missing a closing tag for the row div in the last container.

Comment: I closed the row and made no difference

Comment: Without all the extra CSS, there's nothing we can do to help.